# In IntelliJ or any other IDE, is it somehow possible to show/link the sources of native method calls?

Tags: java

Similar to how you might attach JDK sources, I was wondering if it were somehow possible to show/attach the *native* method implementation sources. I love reading and delving deeper into language sources, and being unable to easily view those sources kind of bugs me.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 14, Intellij provides a decompiler out of the box. As per Eclipse or eclipse based IDEs, there's plenty of good plugins out there that you can find on eclipse Market. One of them is JD.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Could you please go into more detail as to how I might enable that? To clarify: I don't mean decompilation of `.class` files, I mean attaching sources of `native` methods, i.e. `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: @user991710  So are you interested in the native
 c++ code for Linux, Windows etc..?

Comment: That's correct. I would really like being able to look it up more readily than googling to the correct `.cpp` files. Is this possible?

Comment: I tried and failed, I don't think it's possible with intellij.